# Pandas dataframe.to_html() - edit text color and add background color of header columns

Tags: python, html, pandas, pdf-to-html

I am exporting a pandas dataframe as an html table and have been playing around with styling the the header columns in the final table.  Here is an example dataframe I have generated:

```
x = np.arange(0,100,5)
y = np.arange(0,20,1)
example_df = pd.DataFrame(x,y).head(10).reset_index()
example_df.columns = ['X Column', 'Y Column']
```

I have been able to edit the header text color with the following code:

```
example_df = example_df.to_html(index=False).replace('<th>','<th style = "color", "White">')
```

I have also been able to separately alter the background color using the following code:

```
example_df = example_df.to_html(index=False).replace('<th>','<th style = "background-color", "RoyalBlue">')
```

While I have been able to alter the column header text color and background color separately, I have not been able to alter both simultaneously.  Is there a better way to accomplish this so that I am able to alter both the text color and background color rather than choosing between only altering one or the other?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This will work -

```
> example_df.to_html(index=False).replace('<th>','<th style =
> "background-color: royalblue; color: white">')
```